# How to decode following string (dictionary as a string value to outer dictionary key) in Python as JSON?

Tags: python, json

```
t1 = 
     """
        {"abc": "{\"version\": \"1\"}"}
     """
ans = json.loads(t1)
```

Above code results in error as Python doesn't like that I'm providing dictionary as a string value of key "abc".

Assuming I cannot change the input mentioned above, I want to be able to decode the above-mentioned string in Python as JSON, how can I solve this problem?

Comment: For the quotes to be properly escaped you'd need a raw string or double slash, right now what you have is **not** valid JSON so cannot be parsed as such. `print(repr(t1))` to see.

Comment: Try to `json.dumps()` `t1 = {abc: {version: "1"}}`, you'll see it's not the same output as your input.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That's not a valid json string. You need to lose the extra quotes. Only the entire thing needs to be a string, not each individual value.

```
In [1]: t1 = '{"abc": {"version": "1"}}'

In [2]: import json

In [3]: ans = json.loads(t1)

In [4]: ans
Out[4]: {'abc': {'version': '1'}}
```